# How to determine cuda pointer is nullptr?

Tags: c++, memory, cuda, dynamic-memory-allocation

I want to determine a cuda memory is malloced or not in runtime. Or is there a way to determine a cuda pointer is a nullptr or not?

I want to determine the memory in cuda is nullptr or not for different process. I have a function as below.

```cpp
__global__ void func(unsigned int *a, unsigned char *mask, const int len)
{
   if (mask!= nullptr){// do something}
   else {// do something else}
}
```

If the mask is processed by cudaMalloc, it should run into if-condition. Otherwise, it runs into else-condition.

This snippet could run:

```cpp
int* a;
char* mask;
int len = 1024;
cudaMalloc(&a, sizeof(int) * len);
cudaMalloc(&mask, sizeof(char) * len);
func(a, mask, len);
```

**And this snippet could also run:**

```cpp
int* a;
char* mask;
int len = 1024;
cudaMalloc(&a, sizeof(int) * len);
func(a, mask, len);
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, [pointer introspection](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__UNIFIED.html#group__CUDART__UNIFIED) in [device code](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#api-reference) is not possible.

In your host code, if you do:

```
char* mask = nullptr;
```

and you guarantee both of these conditions:

1. If any `cudaMalloc` operation is run (on `mask`), you test the return value and do not allow further code progress (or do not allow any of the snippets that use `mask` to run) if the return value is not `cudaSuccess`
2. There is no usage of `cudaFree` on the `mask` pointer until such point in time where your code snippets that use it will never be run again

Then it should be possible to do what you are suggesting in device code:

```
if (mask!= nullptr){// do something}
else {// do something else}
```

On a successful `cudaMalloc` call, the allocated pointer will never be the `nullptr`.